# How do I fix this alignment?

Tags: alignment

So I'm about to write my thesis and we got these templates to get going with. However, I  don't seem to get the alignment right for a text element on the frontpage, it looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/p9wfK.jpg I would like to have "Faculty of Technology and Society" on one row and "Computer Science" on the second, not  splitting up the last three characters "ety". I have been testing various values in the template, unable to change anything. This is the section I think is relevant:

```
    \renewcommand{\maketitle}{
  \begin{titlepage}
    \global\let\remembered@page\thepage
    \gdef\thepage{\relax}
    \renewcommand{\and}{\\}
    \mbox{}
    \vskip -55mm
    \hskip -5mm
    \begin{picture}(40,20)%
    \includegraphics[scale=0.22]{mau_logo.eps}
    \end{picture}%
    \vskip -16mm
    \hfill
    \begin{minipage}[t]{15em}
      \large
      Faculty of Technology and Society Computer Science %HERE!
    \end{minipage}
    \vskip 60mm
    \begin{center}
      {\bf\large Bachelor's thesis}\par
      {\bf\small\@credits~Credits,~\@level}
      \vskip 25mm
      \if0\mau@lang{

      }\else{
        {\LARGE\@engtitle}
        \vskip 8mm

      }\fi
      \vskip 12mm
      {\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.4}\Large\@author\\}
    \end{center}
    \vfill
    \hskip -10mm
    \begin{minipage}[t]{19em}
      Degree:~\@degree\hfil\\
     ...
```

Do anyone know how I can align the text properly? I have tried inserting line breaks and changing the different sizes. I might add that I use ShareLatex, not sure if it differs from "regular" Latex.

Comment: Did you try to enlarge the minipage: `\begin{minipage}[t]{15em}`? Change `15em` to `20em`

Comment: `\mbox{}
    \vskip -55mm
    \hskip -5mm` is a very strange construct!  (neither `\vskip` nor `\hskip` should appear in a latex document, and `\hskip` does nothing at all there, and the `\vskip` is just backing up over the paragraph that you inserted on the line above which just consists of an empty mbox?

Comment: if your title takes more than one line `{\LARGE\@engtitle}` will produce large text on a small baselinespace you should always include an end of paragraph at the end of the text if you have changed the font size.  `\bf` is not defined by default in latex, and you have not shown a definition in your fragment

Comment: Yeah well this is the template we got, supposdly the teacher updated it for this term... 
@Ignasi changing the em size had no effect.
DavidCarlisle I have no idea what you are talking about hehe. Maybe you could write an answer with code to make it more clear?

Comment: I removed \large and it fixed the problem though the font is a little  small.

Answer (score 1):

You have not provided a usable example so it is impossible to see what the original text looked like, and where it broke the line but from your description it sounds like you want to change

```
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{15em}
  \large
  Faculty of Technology and Society Computer Science %HERE!
\end{minipage}
```

to

```
\hfill
{\large
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}
  Faculty of Technology\\
  and\\
  Society Computer Science %HERE!
\end{tabular}}
```

However the TeX coding in the whole definition is (to put it mildly) very strange. That said, it's only laying out the title page so if it does what you need no real need to change it.